# How to activate a Certificate in IBm Cloud CloudFoundry Applications?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have uploaded my domain certificate (Alpha SSL) to IBM Cloud CloudFoundry application service. The certificate seems correctly accepted and recognized by IBM as I get the green checkmark in the certificate column for the application routes but my application still uses the XXX.eu-gb.mybluemix.net domain certificate so even though the app works, users get the security warning in their browser as the certificate returned by the server does not match my domain

Is there anyway I should activate the use of the domain in the application manifest or similar?

Comment: Are you connecting to the app using the custom domain when it presents the XXX.eu-gb.mybluemix.net certificate?

Comment: Yes... exactly. I have even removed XXX.eu-gb.mybluemix.net from the Routes for that app but even then I still get the IBM domain (Now it is back as an ugly workaround I will install a reverse proxy outside IBM Cloud with the certificate. You can check meanwhile. The website is https://console.tripbru.com

Comment: As a workaround and the lack of response on IBM Cloud ticket support we sent some days ago, we decided to install a HAProxy reverse proxy with the certificate so we get rid of the problem. That is why now https://console.tripbru.com returns the correct certificate. This does not mean the problem is solved on our CloudFoundry app in IBM Cloud.

Comment: @icordoba Do you have a case #? Let me see if I can get you a full answer.

Comment: Yes, it is 61618693. I got a reply just explaining the process of uploading the certificate, which I believe we are doing properly or the domain would not have the green confirmation checkbox next to the SSL certificate and intermediate certificate we have uploaded.

Comment: @icordoba did you get the issue resolvedwith IBM or are you still using that workaround? I have the same issue now

Comment: I am also confused about this

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar and this is how I got it to work. It may not help you, but others. I ran into it while experimenting with Let's Encrypt wildcard certificates my Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes apps (see [here](https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/07/bringing-lets-encrypt-ibm-cloud.html) and [here](https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/07/secure-apps-on-ibm-cloud-kubernetes.html)).

- Use `nslookup` to find out how the name is resolved. Does the IP address point to the IBM server?
- Use `traceroute` to see which path is taken.
- Use different browsers, restart them. I turned to `lynx` as command line browser with some debugging options and used `wget` to fetch an URL.
- Turn off any VPN and Proxy that are used (this was the root cause in my case). The company VPN resolved the DNS with cached information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create CNAME record using one of the `us-east.cf.cloud.ibm.com`, `eu-de.cf.cloud.ibm.com` IBM URLs, depending on the region where you app is hosted.

For example, if your custom domain is `app.mydomain.com` and you've uploaded wildcard `*.mydomain.com` certificate to IBM Cloud, you must make a CNAME entry to point to `app.mydomain.com.us-east.cf.cloud.ibm.com`.  Then if you go to `app.mydomain.com`, your uploaded certificate will be served.